# Troca de conteúdo da variável char

Tags: c, string, memória, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estou tendo dificuldades para trabalhar com arquivos e manipulação de `char`.

#### CÓDIGO

```
char *fileTipoDespesaDefault;
char *fileTipoPagamentoDefault;

FILE *fileTipoDespesa;
FILE *fileTipoPagamento;

/**
 * tipos : 1 => Despesa, 2 => Pagamento
 */
void load(char *arquivo, char modo[2], int tipo){

    FILE *fileOpen = fopen(arquivo, modo);

    switch (tipo){
        case 1:
            fileTipoDespesa = fileOpen;
            break;
        case 2:
            fileTipoPagamento = fileOpen;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main(){

    strcpy(fileTipoDespesaDefault, "tipo_despesa.txt");
    strcpy(fileTipoPagamentoDefault, "tipo_pagamento.txt");

    menuInicial();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

#### SITUAÇÃO

Este código não compila por erro no trecho:

```
strcpy(fileTipoDespesaDefault, "tipo_despesa.txt");
strcpy(fileTipoPagamentoDefault, "tipo_pagamento.txt");
```

Se eu substituir as variáveis para:

```
char fileTipoDespesaDefault[50];
char fileTipoPagamentoDefault[50];
```

Fica tudo ok.

#### DÚVIDA

Teria como fazer algo similar ao PHP?

```
$fileTipoDespesaDefault = "tipo_despesa.txt";
$fileTipoPagamentoDefault= "tipo_pagamento.txt";
```

Meu intuito é poder trocar o conteúdo da variável para qualquer coisa que o usuário passe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro que acontece quando usa a notação de ponteiro é que você não está fazendo a alocação da memória, seja no *heap* com [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) ou, menos comum, no *stack* com [`alloca()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html). O [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) é justamente a forma de atribuir um valor para uma variável "string". É, C, é rápido, é poderoso, mas dá trabalho. Veja [sobre *stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Quando você usa a notação de vetor a alocação é feita pelo compilador no *stack*. Isso tem vantagens e desvantagens como em tudo na computação.

Mas se você tiver uma variável (seu código não mostra isso) que seja uma *string* (na verdade um ponteiro para `char` ou um vetor de `char`) e quiser jogar esse valor para outra *string*, é possível de forma muito simples (pode não funcionar bem em casos mais complexos, mas não importa agora que está aprendendo). Já que você tem dois ponteiros (mesmo na notação de vetor, não deixa de ter um ponteiro), você pode só copiar o ponteiro, desta forma as duas variáveis apontarão para o mesmo conteúdo. Desta forma: `varA = varB;`. Mas se quiser copiar o conteúdo mesmo, só c/ `strcpy()`.

É possível inicializar assim `char fileTipoDespesaDefault[50] = "tipo_despesa.txt";` tomando o cuidado de não tentar colocar um texto maior do que a memória reservada (lembrando que a *string* ainda tem um [caractere oculto no final `\0` ou `NULL`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101)). Mas isto só funciona na declaração da variável. Não funciona para uma simples atribuição.

Se for necessário usar espaços maiores você tem que reservar espaço suficiente para o que for preciso e não deixar "o usuário" (na verdade seu programa é responsável por isto) passar deste limite.

Ou poderá fazer a alocação no *heap* como fez originalmente e ir realocando ([`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)) toda vez que precisa de um espaço maior. Ou seja, tem que gerenciar a memória na mão. Claro que existem bibliotecas que ajudam nisto mas não sei se é sua intenção partir para isto, perde a graça do aprendizado. No caso de usar o ponteiro você tem que declarar a variável, alocar a memória e copiar o conteúdo para ela, não tem jeito.

Fazer `char *fileTipoDespesaDefault = "tipo_despesa.txt";` pode parecer que funciona mas é um perigo porque você estará pegando conteúdo que está em uma área estática da memória, que é somente de leitura e não pode trocar este conteúdo. Claro que ainda pode trocar o ponteiro da variável para outra área da memória (que pode ser escrita).

Pode parecer confuso mas é a forma concreta como o computador funciona. Não tem as abstrações que o PHP fornece. Tudo isto que citei o PHP deve fazer também, mas ele faz por você.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).