# Ponteiro de string não funciona como o esperado

Tags: c, string, ponteiro

Eu estou tentando imprimir o ponteiro de *string* abaixo, e se coloco `" %s " + char* t[];` dá erro, já se coloco `%c` ele imprime a letra `" i "` não sei porque.

Quero aprender e não <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> e <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>)

Também apareceu:

> [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void limpa () {
    fflush(stdin);
}

int main () { setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int inteiro = 1, *i;

    float flutua = 1.0; float* f;

    char texto[20] = "Hello"; char* t; // tentei char* t[] e não deu certo

    i = &inteiro; *i = 2;

    f = &flutua; *f = 2.0;

    limpa();

    t = texto; *t = 'Oi';

    printf("\nOs valores são %i, %.2f, %c.\n",*i,*f,*t); /* coloquei %s e travou o programa
    tipo quandoa gente usa a função abort(); */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem várias coisas esquisitas nesse código, ele não faz nada útil, me parece que não serve nem para aprendizado. Eu consertei os problemas, mas não quiser que agora é um código bom para entender alguma coisa. O maior problema é que a *string* que está com aspas simples que só deve ser usada para um caractere, por isso houve o *warning* indicando que o caractere estava com mais de um caractere. O correto é o uso de aspas duplas para *string*.

Coloquei alguns comentários.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void limpa () {
    fflush(stdin); //isso não serve pra nada aqui
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese"); //nesse código isso é dispensável
    int inteiro = 1, *i;
    float flutua = 1.0;
    float* f;
    char texto[20] = "Hello";
    char t[3]; //deveria declarar e atribuir junto
    i = &inteiro; *i = 2; //isso não faz sentido
    f = &flutua; *f = 2.0; //idem
    limpa();
    strcpy(t, texto); strcpy(t, "Oi"); //para copiar uma string para outra tem que usar strcpy()
    printf("Os valores são %i, %.2f, %s.\n", *i, *f, t); //variável que já é ponteiro passa direto
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4tHesi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ommenrws-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/String.c).

Provavelmente será útil ler:

- [Ponteiro de char ou array de char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101)
- [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)
- [Como uma variável é apontada para um ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91365/101)
- [char[] ou *char malloc?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101)
- [Operador & e * nas funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156278/101)
- [Por que uma atribuição de string em C não funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136628/101)
- [Troca de conteúdo da variável char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40876/101)

Comment: Essas partes " inúteis " são de outro código que eu fiz nesse mesmo arquivo, e sim, ele não faz nada porém é pra mim aprender passagens e tals, muito obrigado por responder e vou ler todos artigos que me indicou agora !

Answer (score 3):

- `char *t;` ponteiro tipo char, aponta para um lugar na memória.
- `t = texto;` isso significa que o t recebe o primeiro índice texto[0] da mesma maneira t vai até o '\0' (caractere de término)
- `*t = 'oi';` isso vai dar um erro, o compilador usa o ' para char e " para array de char. Lembre que a variável t tem texto[0]. Isso quer dizer que é o mesmo que fazer `texto[0] = "Oi";` Isso é erro porque `texto[0]` só recebe um valor. O certo seria `t = 'O';`
- `printf("\nOs valores são %i, %.2f, %c.\n",*i,*f,*t);` Vamos separar o que é `t` e `*t`. Só `t` sem os asterisco informar para publicar o endereço que é texto o mesmo que dizer `printf("%s", texto);`. O segundo com asterisco é informar que para mostra apenas o que está contido na variável `texto[0]` (esse é o motivo que mostra a primeira variável).

**Esse código resolvido seria**

```
t = texto; *t = 'i';`
printf("\nOs valores são %i, %.2f, %s.\n",*i,*f,t);`
```

**Como você poderia escrever oi na variável `t`?**

Primeiro que `texto[20]` tem 20 posições começando do índice 0 até 19
Os endereços seria algo mais ou menos dessa maneira

```
texto[0] = 485201314;
texto[1] = 485201315;
texto[2] = 485201316;
texto[3] = 485201317;
texto[4] = 485201318;
.
.
.
texto[19] = 485201332;
```

Repare no padrão de acréscimo dos array. Isso então nos chega a pensar que só seria fazer isso `*t = 'O'; *(t + 1) = 'i';` Entendeu o funcionamento?
Se pedir para imprimir o Oi acima será imprimido Oillo **Porque** O `printf` irá imprimir até o \0.

Então vamos pensar:

`texto` tem essa frase: `Hello\0` o último é o caractere de término de um array

```
texto[0] = 'H';  
texto[1] = 'e'; 
texto[2] = 'l';  
texto[3] = 'l';   
texto[4] = 'o';   
texto[5] = '\0';
```

Você mudou o primeiro endereço para `O` e o segundo para `i` o resto continuou até o `\0` por isso saiu `Oillo`

Você também poderia andar pelo array através do `t++`, mas isso iria perder o valor `texto[0]`. Para solução poderia usar dois valores assim

```
char *t;
char *comeco_array;

t = texto;
comeco_array = texto;
```

O `t` seria para mudar (`t++`) valores e `comeco_array` seria para imprimir desde o `texto[0]`.

Com `printf("%s", t);` o `t` irá imprimir de onde ele está para frente, se colocar `t++` ele vai imprimir assim: `ello` porque ele começa aonde o `t` está no momento.

Fui claro?

Comment: Rodgger, formatei sua resposta para facilitar a legibilidade. Se não gostou de alguma alteração, pode [edit] novamente, ou reverter para edição anterior pelo histórico, neste link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/160697/revisions

Comment: Editei pelo celular. Dá um desconto. :-)

Comment: Avisei mais pra você saber como reverter caso não tenha gostado do resultado :)