# Qual a diferença entre "NULL", "\0" e 0?

Tags: c, c++, null

Ambos valem zero. Posso usar os 3 intercambiavelmente sempre?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Todos os 3 são literais constantes que valem 0, isso está correto.

## `0`

`0` é um valor numérico e pode ser usado sempre que precisa do número zero mesmo. Em alguns lugares ele acaba sendo usado para outras coisas. Onde se espera um resultado booleano o 0 é considerado falso, enquanto qualquer outro valor é considerado verdadeiro.

## `\0`

Esse é o caractere nulo. Os compiladores costumam definir uma macro chamada `NUL` com este valor, que pode inclusive ter mais que um byte.

Realmente não deixa de ser um 0 e ele geralmente pode ser usado onde se espera um zero. A barra é usada como escape para definir que deseja o byte de valor zero ali e não o caractere `0`, que é algo bem diferente do caractere `0` (é o byte 48). Então essa forma só é usada dentro de um literal caractere ou *string*. Esse caractere é o terminador de *string*. Isto é importante já que C não guarda o tamanho da *string* de forma padronizada.

No caso do `char` é possível usar apenas o `0` mesmo, desde que não use as aspas simples *nem todos compiladores em algumas opções ligadas aceitam). Lembre-se que o tipo `char` é um tipo numérico como outro qualquer. Por acaso ele pode ser usado para imprimir caracteres, mas é apenas uma representação diferente. Computadores só entendem números, o resto é representação.

## `NULL`

Esse é apenas um [`#define`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101) com um valor zerado. De fato há algumas implementações que o valor é `0` mesmo. Mas é mais comum o valor `(void *)0`, deixando claro que na verdade esse é um ponteiro para o endereço zero da memória, portanto um ponteiro nulo.

Um `0` não é tão intercambiável assim. Se tentar comparar um `NULL`, ou seja `void *` com 0 até funciona porque ele faz um *cast* automático. Mas se tentar comparar um `NULL` com um inteiro não acontecerá o que espera. Na verdade é gerado um *warning* e é possível que o compilador nem deixe finalizar.

Um código demonstrando tudo isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    char c = 0;
    char *s = "teste";
    void *p = NULL;
    printf("%d %c %s %p\n", i, c, s, p);
    if (!c) printf("i ok\n"); //verifica se não é zero
    if (!c) printf("c ok\n"); //verifica se não é um caractere nulo
    if (!s[5]) printf("s ok\n"); //verifica se o 6o. caractere é o terminador
    if (!p) printf("p ok\n"); //verifica se o ponteiro não é nulo
//  if (p == i) printf("p NULL ok\n"); //tipos incompatíveis sendo comparados
    printf("%zu", sizeof('x'));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/YabCT6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vqcfgdtc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/ZeroNullTerminator.c).

Answer (score 11):

Queria fazer uma adenda á resposta do @Maniero.

[O Standard C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) nao obriga que `NULL` seja definido com os bits todos a 0.

> §7.20.3.2
>
> ...
>
> 2 The calloc function allocates space for an array of **nmemb** objects, each of whose size is **size**. The space is initialized to all bits zero.<sup>255)</sup>
>
> ...
>
> 255) Note that this need not be the same as the representation of floating-point zero or a null pointer
>   constant.

Tradução:

> §7.20.3.2
>
> ...
>
> 2 A função calloc aloca espaço para um array de **nmemb** objetos, cada um com tamanho **size**. O espaço é inicializado com bits a 0.<sup>255)</sup>
>
> ...
>
> 255) Note que esta não tem que ser a mesma representação do 0 em representação flutuante, ou a constante de ponteiro nulo.

Comment: Muito bom complemento. Eu sempre espero por respostas assim ou mesmo completas para que eu possa aceitar.

Comment: Muito bom mesmo.