# Comparação de variáveis tipo char

Tags: c, comparação, char

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que precisa ler uma variável em `char` e comparar a mesma com outro `char`. Porém ao realizar as comparações utilizando a função `strcmp(typed_pass, correct_pass)`, independente do texto obtido através do `typed_pass`, o resultado é válido, ou seja, retorno 0.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   char correct_pass[] = "test";
   char typed_pass[0];

   do {     
       printf ("\nTo unlock your last tip, enter the correct password: ");
       scanf ("%s", typed_pass);

   } while (strcmp(typed_pass, correct_pass));

   printf ("\nOK!");

   return;
}
```

Já tentei realizar esta operação através de `if` e validações por posição matricial utilizando um `for`, ambos sem sucesso (utilizando o `for` me foi retornado um erro).

Existe outra maneira de fazê-lo ou estou apenas errando na criação das variáveis?

Comment: Está correto definir a variável `typed_pass` com tamanho 0?

Comment: Imaginei que definindo o tamanho para 0, o espaço de alocação de caracteres se tornaria dinâmico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, a comparação está sendo feita com um *array*  de caracteres. E está comparando um de tamanho 5 com um de tamanho 0, claro que isso não dá certo, fazendo o *array* do tamanho correto funciona, ainda que ainda possa ter alguns outros problemas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char correct_pass[] = "test";
    char typed_pass[10];
    do {     
        printf ("\nTo unlock your last tip, enter the correct password: ");
        scanf ("%s", typed_pass);
    } while (strcmp(typed_pass, correct_pass));
    printf ("\nOK!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/S7Pxv5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/axjmwwxp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StringCorrectLenght.c).

Ficaria melhor com:

```
scanf ("%9s", typed_pass);
```

Na verdade o `scanf()` é até desincentivado, mas para coisas simples assim é ok.

Comment: bigown, por quê o array de caracteres teria tamanho 5 contendo o texto *test*? Lembro-me vagamente de estudar na faculdade sobre o caractere `\0` finalizando uma *string*. Seria esse o motivo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso mesmo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101

Comment: Você citou que ainda pode ocorrer outros problemas. Pode me mostrar uma forma melhor de escrever este código?

Comment: @Drythz O principal e que vale falar agora, enquanto está aprendendo é que o `scanf()` pode ler mais que 10 caracteres.

Comment: @Drythz e, dando seguimento ao que o bigown disse, é bom criar o hábito de usar o especificador `%9s` em vez de `%s` quando se está passando um vetor de 10 caracteres para leitura, `%31s` quando se passa um vetor de 32 posições, etc. Assim se evita toda uma classe de problemas chamados de _buffer overflow_.