# Algo mais simples do que isso para alocar um texto digitado dinamicamente?

Tags: c, memória, malloc

```
// FUNCAO //
char *nome(char text[20])
{
   char *n;
   int n2;
   int n3 = 0;
   printf("%s\n",text);
   while((n2 = getchar()) != '\n' && n2 != EOF)
   {      
       if(n3 < 1)
       {
            n = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));// alocando 1 bytes
            *n = n2;// posicao 0 e = letra digitada
            n3++; // encrementando 1 pra sair da condicao if
       }
       // Daqui pra frente só realoca //
       n3++; 
       n = (char*) realloc(n, n3*sizeof(char));
       *(n+(n3-1)) = n2;
    }
    return n;// retorna o ponteiro
 }
 //Usando a funcao //
 char *name = nome("Nome:");// texto antes de digitar o nome 
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // ignora i < 5 ainda vo mexer aqui 
       printf("%c", *(name+i)); // mostra o nome    
 free(name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem pequenas melhorias que podem ser feitas no código, a maioria só cosmética, estilística e coisas do tipo, até para favorecer a legibilidade que está ruim.

Poderia colocar um [caractere nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101) no final para que se tornasse uma *string*  e aí não precisaria do laço para imprimir a *string*. O que alias está errado, a única solução para resolver o tamanho a ser impresso é o caractere nulo ou retornar também o tamanho de alguma forma. De fato o 5 está errado.

Note que é pouco provável que deseje deixar a entrada ilimitada. E que não costuma ter nada de errado em alocar o valor máximo que a *string* pode ser entrada. Mesmo que o máximo seja um pouco grande demais ainda dá pra otimizar as alocações.

É comum começar com um tamanho mínimo, tipo 16, 64, 256 ou até mais. E ir dobrando a alocação com o [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) sempre que estourar a capacidade. Tem que controlar o tamanho ocupado e confrontar com a capacidade total para decidir de deve realocar.

Além disto `sizeof(char)` é sempre 1, então isto é desnecessário, o *cast* `(char*)` é inadequado em C.

Não precisa fazer a primeira alocação como exceção no `if`, o `realloc()` basta desde o ponteiro começo como nulo.

Comment: deu certo iniciar o ponteiro como nulo e depois só realocar,  mais eu não entendi muito bem, tem como explicar melhor esse negócio vlw

Comment: Tem como perguntar melhor esse negócio?

Comment: porque iniciar como nulo ? tem uma explicçao

Comment: Porque aí a relocação ocorre de nada (o nulo) para algum lugar. Portanto o efeito é o mesmo do `malloc()`, ele aloca algo novo, mas como não tem nada para desalocar, tudo funciona como o esperado, assim elimina a exceção no algoritmo.

Comment: vlw a ajuda, e pro laço eu usei: for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++){ mostra}

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101 Eu não faria assim. Nem usaria um *loop*.

Comment: to tendo um problema com while quando eu uso o free() ele da um erro, já sem o free ele vai normal, muito estranho

Comment: Isto parece ser outro problema, faça uma pergunta com detalhes para podermos ajudar.