# Vetor de char por referência

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, arduino, char

Estou tentando passar uma *array* de `char` para uma *procedure* que irá redimensionado (com `malloc()`), escrever seu conteúdo e voltar ao `main()`.

Sei que todo vetor é um ponteiro e já é passado por referência, mas algo no meu software não esta deixando isso acontecer, quando voltar para a função `main()` ele esta com os valores iniciais, segue código de exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void proc(char msg[])
{
    unsigned int i;

    msg = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    msg[0] = 'a';
    msg[1] = 'b';
    msg[2] = 'c';
    msg[3] = 'd';
    msg[4] = 'e';
    msg[5] = 'f';
    msg[6] = 'g';
    msg[7] = 'h';
    msg[8] = 'i';
    msg[9] = 'j';

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", msg[i]);
        msg[i] = 'x';
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main ()
{
    char msg[] = "12345";
    unsigned int i;

    printf("Before proc\n");

    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", msg[i]);
    }

    printf("\nin proc ======\n");

    proc( msg );

    printf("After proc\n");

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", msg[i]);
    }

    printf("FIM");
    return 0;
}
```

A saída é a seguinte:

> ```
> bash-4.2$ ./a.out
> Before proc
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
>
> in proc ======
> a
> b
> c
> d
> e
> f
> g
> h
> i
> j
>
> After proc
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
>
>
>
>
>
> FIM
> ```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Qual é o objetivo? A função está bem esquisita, faz coisas meio sem nexo.

Comment: Fiz só um exemplo para tentar isolar o problema que estou tendo ao ler uma porta serial, o que quero é:

1. passar um array de char para uma procedure
2. redimencionar esse array na procedure
3. escrever valores nessa array
4. retornar o main com a array dimencionada e com os novos valores

Comment: Ou seja, qualdo voltar para o main o vetor tem que estar todo preenchido com 'x' e ter tamanho de 10 bytes.

Comment: Você começa trabalhando com uma *string*, depois abando na isto, qual é o correto, é uma *string* ou não?

Comment: O correto é trabalhar o tempo todo com uma string, posso estar errando exatamente nisso, mas tem que ser dinámico.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários erros e complicações. Mantive as escritas para ver funcionando, mas obviamente que isto não deveria existir aí.

Se vai trabalhar com *string* faça o tempo todo assim. Precisa ter espaço para o [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101).

Se vai alterar o tamanho então precisa alocar o *array* dinamicamente com `malloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void proc(char msg[]) {
    msg = realloc(msg, 11);
    strcpy(msg, "xxxxxxxxxx");
    printf("\nin proc ======\n%s\n", msg);
}

int main() {
    char *msg = malloc(6);
    strcpy(msg, "12345");
    printf("Before proc\n%s", msg);
    proc(msg);
    printf("After proc\n%s\nFIM", msg);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vyM71N). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bvkpxlqg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ChangeSize.c).

Não liberei a memória com [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) porque em tese iria usar em outro lugar.

Não verifiquei se a alocação funcionou, o que torna o código menos robusto. O normal é fazer isto com [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) e [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Mas em determinados contextos nada disso é o correto e precisa de uma solução bem diferente desta, especialmente em ambientes embarcados.

Comment: Obrigado, tem algum exemplo ou referência de como fazer isso em sistemas embarcados?

Comment: Depende do que precisa fazer.

Comment: Quero tratar o que vem pela serial mas não sei o tamanho do que vem na serial, por isso estou fazendo array dinamica.

Comment: Precisa criar uma estratégia de *buffer*, mas me parece que é algo avançado para seu conhecimento e depende de várias coisas para decidir como fazer.

Comment: Se fiver um treixo de código vou estudando, mas por hora obrigado.