# Colocar string em uma matriz de caracteres

Tags: c, c++, string, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estou aprendendo matriz de caracteres e queria fazer um programa simples em que eu crio uma matriz de caracteres 200x100, coloco uma *string* na posição 0 e a imprimo.

Isso é parte de um programa maior que estou fazendo, mas preciso entender como inserir uma *string* na matriz de caracteres para fazer.

Sei que para o usuário inserir é só colocar o `gets(x[i])`, mas preciso colocar pelo código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    char mat[200][100];
    mat[0] = "paulo";
    printf("%s", mat[0]);
    getch();
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char mat[200][100];
    strcpy(mat[0], "paulo");
    printf("%s", mat[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/huwBKA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dthrzlcq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Assign.c).

Precisa copiar os dados manualmente da área estática para a pilha. Lembrando que o nome só pode ter até 99 caracteres por causa do [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101).

É possível usar ponteiros e acessar o conteúdo diretamente na área estática, mas ele não pode ser trocado ali. É possível trocar o ponteiro que inicialmente apontava para área estática e depois poderia apontar para a pilha ou pra o monte (*heap*).