# Ponteiro para char no printf() não funciona

Tags: c, ponteiro

Resolvi fazer esse código simples, onde tenho um vetor vazio e uma função que preenche ele apenas com uma letra que o usuário digitar, mas não estou conseguindo imprimir.

Se uso aquele `printf()` comentado, ele funciona, mas se imprimo fora não da nada. E se tento imprimir la na função `main()`, sai com m 2 no final. Por que?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM 3

void preencher(char *str, char letra){
    int c;

    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        *str = letra;
        //printf("%c", *str);
        *str++;
    }

    while (*str) printf("%c", str++);
}

int main(){
    char str[TAM], letra;

    scanf("%c", &letra);

    preencher(&str, letra);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros neste código. Está passando um *array* por referência, sendo que todo *array* já é uma referência.

Se vai usar uma variável para andar pelo *array*, use-a em vez de acessar o ponteiro direto. Se vai acessar o ponteiro não crie uma variável. Mas eu criaria a variável porque andar pelo *array* sem copiar seu endereço fará o apontamento original mudar de posição e terá problemas posteriores, que é o principal problema que não consegue usar depois.

Não está colocando o [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101) que toda *string* precisa (imagino que esteja querendo criar uma *string*.

Para imprimir nem precisa fazer nada além de chamar a função de impressão como *string*. Se quiser fazer na mão, é o mesmo código do preenchimento, só que faz a impressão.

Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 3

void preencher(char *str, char letra) {
    for (int c = 0; c < TAM - 1; c++) str[c] = letra;
    str[TAM - 1] = 0;
    printf("%s", str);
}

int main(){
    char str[TAM], letra;
    scanf("%c", &letra);
    preencher(str, letra);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CKdwHP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gorqwxhi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Fill.c).

Tem maneiras melhores de fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

O @Maniero já lhe indicou os vários erros que tinha, mas eu acho importante referir que deve sempre estar atento ao que está a tentar fazer, pois em muitos casos já existem funções prontas para tal.

No caso você já inclui `<string.h>`, logo pode utilizar a função [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) que lhe permite atribuir um valor a uma zona de memória byte a byte. Se estiver a atribuir em um vetor de `char` irá funcionar como esperado.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM 3

int main(){
    char str[TAM + 1]; //+1 para o terminador
    char letra;
    scanf("%c", &letra);
    memset(str, letra, TAM); //colocar a letra repetidamente, igual ao preencher que tinha
    str[TAM] = '\0'; //colocar o terminador no fim da string
    printf("%s", str); //mostrar
}
```

Note que eu usei o tamanho da *string* como `TAM + 1` e coloquei o terminador em `TAM`, ficando efetivamente com `TAM` letras escritas. Alternativamente pode alocar apenas `TAM` e colocar o terminador em `TAM - 1` (como fez o @Maneiro), ficando com `TAM - 1` letras escritas.

[Veja o código no Ideone](https://ideone.com/T6TXXQ)

Answer (score 0):

Caso queira imprimir um vetor de caracteres ao inves de uma string,pode fazer o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM 3

void preencher(char *str,char letra){

int c;

printf("Conteudo do vetor: ");

 for (c=0; c < TAM; c++){
    str[c] = letra;
    printf("%c ", str[c]);
 }

}

int main(){

char str[TAM], letra;

printf("Digite uma letra:");
scanf("%c", &letra);

preencher(str,letra);
return 0;

}
```