# Como dar 'valor' a uma variável do tipo char?

Tags: c, char

Como eu consigo dar valor para a variável `char` sem ser pelo comando `scanf()`? Por exemplo, tenho uma variável chamada `nome` e quero dizer que ela vale `maria`.

Comment: Escolha uma resposta que respondeu à sua pergunta, isso ajuda bastante a comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[6]="maria";
```

É isso?
maria possui 5 caracteres, mas tem de reservar +1 por causa do '\0', então reservamos 6 de memoria estatica

Answer (score 2):

Bom, colocar "maria" em uma variável do tipo `char` não dá porque este tipo espera apenas um caractere, é possível fazer isto em um ponteiro para uma área devidamente alocada na memória, o que pode ser na *stack* como um vetor, o mais fácil, mas menos comum em código real. Assim:

```
char nome[6] = "maria";
```

neste caso o que está fazendo é criar uma área na pilha de execução reservando 6 caracteres, portanto 5 para o nome que quer armazenar mais o [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101) necessário para toda *string*. E neste local será colocado um valor já estabelecido na área estática da memória da aplicação.

Então esta é a forma mais simples de fazer sem intervenções extras.

Uma outra sintaxe esquisita que funciona seria:

```
char nome[6] = { 'm', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'a', '\0' };
```

Se for no *heap*:

```
char nome = malloc(6);
strcpy(nome, "maria");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Copy.c).