# Por que é possível armazenar uma cadeia de caracteres em um ponteiro de char?

Tags: c, c++, string, ponteiro, memória

Por que `char` armazena um único caractere e o ponteiro aponta para o valor dele na memória, então ele não deveria possuir apenas um caractere? Exemplo:

```
char *str = "Ola";
```

Por que `str` não armazena apenas um caractere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pergunta parte de uma premissa errada. Não está armazenando uma cadeia de caracteres em um ponteiro de `char`.

A cadeia de caracteres está sendo armazenada em uma área estática da memória, geralmente a *data segment*. `str` está realmente armazenando um ponteiro para `char` (4 ou 8 bytes de acordo com a arquitetura), então obviamente um endereço. Que endereço é esse? O endereço onde começa a cadeia de caracteres na área estática da memória.

Lembrando que [toda *string* em C tem um caractere extra de terminação indicando seu fim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101). Nesse exemplo há 4 *bytes* na área estática.

Faz sentido agora?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).