# Inicializar uma função que tem um ponteiro de string como argumento

Tags: c, algoritmo

Escrevi uma função que troca a letra de uma *string* pela sua sucessora usando um ponteiro de *string*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
14) Implemente um algoritmo que receba uma string como parâmetro e substitua todas as letras
por suas sucessoras no alfabeto. Por exemplo, a string “Casa” seria alterada para “Dbtb”.
A letra z deve ser substituída pela letra a (e Z por A). Caracteres que não forem letras devem
permanecer inalterados.
*/

    void shift_string (char* str)
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (str[i] != 0)
        {
            if (str[i] == 'z') str[i] = 'a';
            else if (str[i] == 'Z') str[i] ='A';
            else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] < 'z') str[i]++;
            else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] < 'Z') str[i]++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    int main() {

        char original[10] = {"Casa"};
        char shifted[10] = shift_string(original);

        printf("%s\n", original);
        printf("%s\n", shifted);

        return 0;
    }
```

Minha dúvida está na inicialização da função `shift_string()` no `main()`, porque está dando erro "Invalid Initializer" no Dev C++.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Por que está declarando uma *string*, portanto seu inicializador é um texto entre aspas duplas, mais nada. O uso das chaves faz com que esteja inicializando o que seria um *array*, que não é o que deseja, portanto é inválido.

Em C é até possível inicializar uma *string* como se fosse um *array* de caracteres, porque é isto mesmo que é a *string*, mas aí não poderia usar as aspas, teria que criar cara um dos caracteres como elementos separados, teria que ser cada um deles com aspas simples, e ter um [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101) colocado manualmente.

Tem que escolher um ou outro inicializador (até pode usar ambos no cenário adequado onde tenha um *array* de *strings*, que não é o caso), e neste caso parece que o mais simples é inicializar só com as as aspas:

```
char original[10] = "Casa";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Initialization.c).

O código pode ser simplificado e escrito de forma mais idiomática. E tem ainda um erro conceitual e de lógica. Ele está mudando o original e não está retornando alguma coisa, mas parece que espera que retorne.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui melhorar a lógica do código e fazer ele funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
14) Implemente um algoritmo que receba uma string como parâmetro e substitua todas as letras
por suas sucessoras no alfabeto. Por exemplo, a string “Casa” seria alterada para “Dbtb”.
A letra z deve ser substituída pela letra a (e Z por A). Caracteres que não forem letras devem
permanecer inalterados.
*/

void shift_string (char str[50])
{
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] == 'z') str[i] = 'a';
        else if (str[i] == 'Z') str[i] ='A';
        else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] < 'z') str[i]++;
        else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] < 'Z') str[i]++;
        i++;
    }
    puts(str);
}

int main() {

    char str[50] = "Casa";

    shift_string(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sem tem uma dúvida especifica em relação a ponteiros, abra uma nova pergunta focando essa dúvida em particular.