# Passagem por referência de vetor de struct

Tags: c, array, struct, passagem-por-referência

Tenho que fazer um exercício onde gero uma `struct` e um vetor seguindo essa `struct` com um tamanho N de casas (o qual chamei no código de `QTD`) inseridos pelo usuário.

Após isso o programa permite exibir essa lista de dados inseridos, porém, meu problema é na passagem por referência de um vetor de `structs`. Isto é, como funciona? É uma passagem por referência de um vetor qualquer?

Minha ideia é criar uma função `preencher()` e dentro dela realizar esse preenchimento, segue o código:

```
typedef struct {

    int id;
    char nome[200];
    char endereco[100];
    char cidade [30];

}Struct1 ;

Struct1 vetorStruct1[QTD]; // vetor de struct que deve ser utilizado 

void preencher( struct Struct1 *vetorStruct1[], int QTD ){ //LINHA NA QUAL ESTOU EM DÚVIDA!!!


int i;

printf("Insira a quantidade de funcionários que serão cadastrados: ");
scanf("%d",&QTD );
printf("\nQTD:%d\n",QTD);

system("pause");
system("cls");


for(i=0; i<QTD; i++) {

printf(" Digite o ID do funcionário: ");
scanf("%d*c", &vetorStruct1[i].id);

printf(" Digite a nome do funcionário: ");
scanf("%s*c", &vetorStruct1[i].nome);

printf(" Digite o endereco do funcionário: ");
scanf("%s*c", &vetorStruct1[i].endereco);

printf(" Digite o cidade do funcionário: ");
scanf("%s*c", &vetorStruct1[i].cidade);

printf(" DADOS DO FUNCIONARIO DE ID %d CADASTRADOS! \n",vetorStruct1[i].id);

system("pause");
system("cls");

}
}

int main() // será somente um switch case entre o preencher e o imprimir.
```

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida ou se está tendo problemas. Tem várias perguntas, mas nenhuma muito especifica a não ser a segunda que a resposta é sim. Onde você alocou o vetor?

Comment: Como funciona essa passagem de referência por vetor? é isso que não sei muito bem, to estudando na raça e algumas coisas passam sem entender..

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi ajudar porque tem uma quantidade extraordinária de erros no código. O ideal é aprender uma coisa de cada vez, assim comete só um erro, aprende com ele, segue para o próximo e aí vai evoluindo o conhecimento. Quando tenta fazer o que ainda não está preparado comete muitos erros e não aprende com eles. Um dos erros e não ter colocado o código de forma mais organizada para ajudarmos melhor. Programação é muito de organização, quem não consegue fazer isto terá dificuldades na profissão.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char nome[201];
    char endereco[101];
    char cidade [31];
} Pessoa;

void preencherPessoas(Pessoa pessoas[], int qtde) {
    for (int i = 0; i < qtde; i++) {
        printf(" Digite o ID do funcionário: ");
        scanf("%d", &pessoas[i].id);
        printf(" Digite a nome do funcionário: ");
        scanf("%s", pessoas[i].nome);
        printf(" Digite o endereco do funcionário: ");
        scanf("%s", pessoas[i].endereco);
        printf(" Digite o cidade do funcionário: ");
        scanf("%s", pessoas[i].cidade);
        printf(" DADOS DO FUNCIONARIO DE ID %d CADASTRADOS! \n", pessoas[i].id);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Insira a quantidade de funcionários que serão cadastrados: ");
    int qtde;
    scanf("%d", &qtde);
    printf("\nQTD: %d", qtde);
    Pessoa pessoas[qtde];
    preencherPessoas(pessoas, qtde);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bRJIc6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sgsffaia-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ArrayPass.c).

- Dei um nome que quer dizer alguma coisa no tipo da estrutura criada. Código é expressão, é importante dar bons nomes para as coisas para entender melhor o que está fazendo. Todo programador experiente faz isso, só novato não dá valor para isto.
- Coloquei mais 1 byte nas *strings* para cabe o [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101). Os tamanhos são absurdamente grandes e desperdiçam muito espaço e qualquer quantidade de dados maior estourará a *stack*. Não vou entrar em detalhes, mas toda essa ideia de organização da `struct` está errada e códigos reais não são assim. Ele serve só para entender outras coisas neste pequeno código, tenha isso em mente.
- Não declare variáveis globais, a não ser que tenha um domínio muito grande do que está fazendo, só declare variáveis locais.
- Dê nome melhor para a função. O que aconteceria se tivesse que preencher outra coisa?
- Se criou um tipo então o use não fique usando a `struct` para declarar variáveis e parâmetros.
- Não precisa passar o *array* por referência porque ele já é uma referência. Só precisaria passar assim se fosse trocar o objeto inteiro, o que não é o caso, inclusive nem dá para fazer isso na forma programada.
- Não precisa declarar a variável antes do seu uso, na verdade isto torna o código menos legível
- Nomes usando notação ALL_CAPS só deveria ser usada para macros, e mesmo assim devem ser evitadas. E não precisa abreviar tanto, use uma abreviatura mais comum.
- Uma função que deve preencher os dados das pessoas não deve perguntar quantas pessoas serão no total. Isso é responsabilidade de outra função.
- Se o dado é uma *string* então ele já é um *array*, portanto já é uma referência e o `scanf()` pede uma referência, então não precisa criar outra referência quando passa este dado, já é naturalmente o que espera.
- Criei um `main()` que faz sentido.

Se não entendeu alguma coisa é porque pulou passos demais. Aqui no site tem quase tudo o que precisa saber antes de continuar.