# A condicional não funciona como esperado (relacionada à tabela ASCII)

Tags: c, string, char

```
int tam, i;
char msg[1000];
printf("Escreva a mensagem para ser criptografada: ");
fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);

tam = strlen(msg);

for (i=0; i<tam; i++) {
    int aux;
    aux = msg[i];
    if ("A"<=msg[i]<="B" || "a"<=msg[i]<="z") { // O problema acontece aqui
        msg[i] = msg[i]+3;
    } else {
        msg[i]== aux;
    }
}
```

Quando eu entro com `"Texto #3"`, o programa só deve alterar os caracteres entre 65 e 90 ou entre 97 e 122. Porém, no caractere *space* (32) e todos os outros entram no primeiro na condicional.

O resultado sai `Wh{wr#&6`, e o esperado era `Wh{wr #3`.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você queria usar aspas simples (apostrofe) e não duplas. Há uma grande diferença entre elas. as aspas simples indicam um único caractere e as aspas duplas indica uma sequência de [caracteres terminada por um valor nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101). Ainda que tenha apenas um caractere, ela é considerado uma sequência de um caractere válido e ainda tem o terminador, e ainda precisa comparar todos os caracteres da sequência para indicar igualdade, mas não parece que deseja isto, só quer compara um caractere.

Além disto este código nem compila, pelo menos na forma apresentada, então ou apresentou um diferente do que está usando ou está informando um erro diferente do que acontece. Há um erro na construção da expressão booleana dentro do `if` misturando operandos de forma inapropriada, você não pode usar como na matemática, só pode comparar dois operandos de cada vez nos operadores.

Não estou avaliando a lógica porque a pergunta não deixa isto tão claro, pode ter erro aí também.

Vou simplificar algumas coisas e fazer como é o correto em C.

```
char msg[1000];
printf("Escreva a mensagem para ser criptografada: ");
fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
for (int i = msg; *i != '\0'; i++) *i = ((*i >= 'A' && *i <= 'Z') || (*i >= 'a' && *i <= 'z')) ? *i + 3 : *i;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Char/CaesarCipher.c).

Na verdade tem um erro de lógica óbvio aí. Se faltar 3 letras para terminar o alfabeto ele deve começar de novo lá no início, então as letras Y, W e Z deveria se transformar em A, B ou C. Deixo para você acertar isso até para dar continuidade no exercício.

Veja: [Sempre que vou varrer um string em C devo usar o "strlen()", certo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se isso cobre o código inteiro, mas posso dizer que tem dois problemas no seu `if`

Primeiro que a comparação `a <= b <= c` não funciona em C, pois o compilador primeiro irá comparar `a` com `b`, gerando o resultado 0 (false) ou 1 (true), e então irá comparar esse 0 ou 1 com `c`, o que não é o que você quer. O certo seria `a <= b && b <= c`

Segundo que o que você declara entre aspas duplas é um array de caracteres (uma string literal), enquanto o que você declara entre aspas simples é um caractere, quando você compara `"A" <= msg[i]`, você está usando o ponteiro que aponta para o primeiro caractere da string `"A"` para a comparação, não o caractere `'A'`.

Comment: Obrigado, eram esses os dois erros.