# Comparar elementos da String em C

Tags: c, string, comparação, char

Gostaria de separar uma palavra e comparar cada elemento da string com uma letra, tentei fazer esta comparação utilizar o `strcmp()` porém quando executo parece ignora-lo, ou não executa.

Quando retiro a condição a função separa a palavra normalmente porém não consigo armazenar a letra nem compara-la.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  char str[20];
  gets(str);
  int i;
  int strLength = strlen(str);

  for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {

      if (strcmp(str[i],"c") == 0)
      {
        printf("Achei");
      }

      printf("[%c]", str[i]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Se você quer comparar uma determinada posição de sua string com um caractere use: `if (str[i] == 'c')
      {
        printf("Achei");
      }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou te passar algumas coisas para aprender como codificar corretamente:

- Não use `gets()`, essa função é problemática e é considerada obsoleta. [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) é o [caminho correto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101). Eu protegi o acesso indevido de memória pegando só a quantidade de caracteres possíveis na área reservada já que existe o [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101).
- Variáveis devem ser declaradas no menor escopo possível, então a variável do `for` deve ser declarada nele mesmo, não use um padrão de código que era usado há 30 ou 40 anos atrás por deficiência do compilador.
- Não pegue o tamanho de *string* com [`strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101), em C é muito ineficiente porque faz um laço, e você já está fazendo um laço, apenas teste se chegou no fim, porque não precisa saber o tamanho dela.
- Quando pega um elemento de uma *string* está pegando um caractere, então deve comparar com outro caractere, e não com uma *string*. A função que usou é necessária para comparar *strings* (internamente tem um laço nela).
- Esse pode ser um caso para fazer assim porque é exercício, mas saiba que tem uma função pronta e eficiente (apesar de ser um laço foi pensada para ser o melhor possível), é a [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Veja como fica mais simples e legível:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[20];
    fgets(str, 19, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'c') printf("Achei");
        printf("[%c]", str[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jH7SCe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FindCharc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/FindChar.c).

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme, o problema é que você está usando a função `strcmp` para comparar um caractere a outro, quando seu uso, na verdade, deve ser a comparação entre cadeias de caracteres.

Nesse caso, portanto, você compara direto, sem o uso da função. Seu código fica assim:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char str[20];
gets(str);
int i;
int strLength = strlen(str);

for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {

  if (str[i] == 'c')
  {
    printf("Achei");
  }

  printf("[%c]", str[i]);

 }
}
```