# Como funciona o acesso à strings em um array?

Tags: c, lógica, princípios-de-programação

> Criar um programa que receba a data em numeral e depois retorne ela por extenso.

Tentei fazer algumas vezes, mas acabei mesclando meu código com um que achei de um fórum e saiu assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Date(int day, int month, int year);

int main(void){
    int day, month, year;
    
    printf("\nDay(1-31): ");
    scanf("%i", &day);

    //limpa o buffer de entrada.
     getchar();

    printf("\nMonth(1-12): ");
    scanf("%i", &month);
    
    //limpa o buffer de entrada.
    getchar();

    printf("\nYear(xxxx): ");
    scanf("%i", &year);

    Date(day, month, year);

    return 0;
}

void Date(int day, int month, int year){
    const char* months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                               "May", "June", "July", "August",
                               "Setember", "October", "November", "Dezember"};
    system ("clear"); //gnu-linux

    printf("The Date is: %s %dth, %d\n", months[month - 1], day , year);

   
}
```

Daí me surgiram duas dúvidas sobre o final deste código:

1 - por que é necessário o [month - 1]?

2 - por que o vetor não tem nenhum valor dentro para alocar?

3 - por que é necessário declarar `const` na variável char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - por que é necessário o [month - 1]?

Porque [*arrays* começam em 0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183798/101), então se digitou o mês 1 deve pegar o índice 0, se foi 2 deve pegar 1, e assim por diante até o índice 11 que é o mês 12 que conhecemos.

> 2 - por que o vetor não tem nenhum valor dentro para alocar?

O compilador consegue inferir isso lendo os valores que foram atribuídos para ele, mas há um valor, só não está visível no código.

> 3 - por que é necessário declarar const na variavel char?

Os valores de texto que tem ali está em uma área estática da memória, portanto uma área que não pode ser modificada. Literais `string` são sempre assim. Não é um local que pode manipular, então se tentar a aplicação quebra. Se colocar `const` o compilador sabe que não pode mexer ali então ele dá erro quando for compilar se tentar modificar algo ali, e esse erro é bem melhor que um erro quando está executando. Veja mais em [De onde vem o espaço na memória necessário para cada elemento em um array de strings em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446248/101). Também: [Troca de conteúdo da variável char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40876/101).